# Keeping height and width equal while responsive in a <div> with different height and widths

Tags: css

Basically I want to create a circle in css. my code for the circle is:

```
.circle{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
}
```

it's sitting in a div that is:

```
.banner{
  width:100%;
  height:13em;
}
```

obviously the circle won't be a circle because I have the widths and heights for it percentage based but the container surrounding it has different widths and heights. Is there a way to make the circle have the same dimensions, or would I have to do math to figure it out?

Comment: share some markup or a fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewport-percentage length `vw`. It is a valid css dimension, like `px` for pixels or `em` for current font size.

Since that the `vw` refers to the width of the viewport, using `20vw` for width or height or any other property will not make any difference, it will always have the same value.

So basically you will do:

```
.circle{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:20vw;
    height:20vw;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9fa/167/**

There are some more viewport-based dimensions, like `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax`, for a complete list and explanation **see the documentation here**: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths